# Recover a file deleted using rm command in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover a removed file under linux](https://superuser.com/questions/150027/how-to-recover-a-removed-file-under-linux)

I have accidentally deleted a very-very important file in my Linux (Ubuntu) machine using the command `rm`.

Is there any way to recover it?