# Accidentally i have deleted folders thourgh SSH connection, can i recover files using ssh?

Tags: eclipse, ssh, debian, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover a removed file under linux](https://superuser.com/questions/150027/how-to-recover-a-removed-file-under-linux)

Accidentally I have deleted folders from eclipse remote system explore I have connected server through SSH.

Its possible to recover file using SSH command line?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is a unix box.  There is no magic undelete.  There are some hacks that a skilled sysadmin might be able to pull off depending on file system, but those are dangerous and must be done on a backed up filesystem, typically with the machine in single user mode. In summary, those files are lost.