# How can I know what subfolders rm -rf attempted to delete first?

Tags: linux, rm

I mistakenly run `rm -rf` on a wrong folder and than cancel the operation after two seconds.
The folder is quite big with many subfolders and maybe 1% was deleted.

How can I know what `subfolders` rm attempted to delete first?
That can help me to determine what files I need to restore.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but might help you somehow: http://superuser.com/questions/150027/how-to-recover-a-removed-file-under-linux (How to recover a removed file under Linux?)

Answer (score -1):

Won't be easy to restore names of already removed directories, but executing `ls -l *` probably will give a clue how shell expanded `*` wildcard.

Comment: If that was the case, I got lucky.