# How to bring linux machine to multi-user mode

Tags: linux, ssh, data-recovery

I am using centos7 as my local system. I have installed vagrant vitual box, but by mistake I have deleted a file in the VM. To recover file I was following [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/150027/how-to-recover-a-removed-file-under-linux) but **there are command for remote system. So I by mistake I ran the following command.**

```
# wall
System is going down to .... please save your work.

Press CTRL+D to send message.

Next use init 1 command to take system to a single user mode:

# init 1
```

Now every time  I ssh into my VM, I get the message "The system is going down to rescue mode NOW!"

How can I restore the previous configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Use again the `init` command giving a different runlevel as argument (for example `init 3`).

You can see the default runlevel used by your box looking for the entry `initdefault` inside `/etc/inittab`